# How to group on a separate dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, sum

Currently my query looks like this

```
Select A, B,  count (C) as Quantity, sum (D) as Fee,
       (select ABC from Mappings where MT = A) as 'Dog',
       (select ACD from Mappings where MT = A) as 'Cat'
from @mt
where A in (select MT from Mappings where AED in (@Cli))
group by A, B
```

Currently my data is counting and suming data on A but i want the data to be counted and sumed on by Cat.

Is there a way to group the data on another column

I am using t-sql

Any help is appreciated

Comment: hard to tell what you're asking.  if you don't want to group by A then remove it from the query.

Comment: Please provide table structures, sample data, and expected output given that sample data. It's the easiest way for others to understand what you're looking for and to provide you with help. Also, please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since no aggregate calculations are happening to `A` or `B` they both need to remain in your `GROUP BY` clause.  If you don't need those (or 'Dog') in the final result, you could try the following:

```
Select (select ACD from Mappings where MT = A) as 'Cat'
count (C) as Quantity, 
sum (D) as Fee
from @mt
where A in (select MT from Mappings where AED in (@Cli))
group by (select ACD from Mappings where MT = A)
```